# How the set function works cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

What is the logic behind cakephp set function, that the variable is available in view file after set from controller (How this happens?)

Comment: "How this happens?" Seriously? Just read the code of the set() method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for the set function:

[CakePHP's set function](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Controller.html#824-844)

To fully understand it you should also read the render function. In CakePHP views are assumed to have the same name as the public function so it's not common to see render in the controller as you would see a lot, for example, in Yii Framework.

[CakePHP's render function](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Controller.html#911-958)